Java Swing does not display Unicode glyphs
I am trying to display few Unicode characters (glyphs) in my application. The characters can be ASCII (Basic Latin), CJK, Emojis etc. - should be able to display all the (printable) characters in the Unicode character database.
Eventually, the display must happen in a text editor (JTextArea). But many characters are being shown as tofus, which I think is a font issue.
// here "myText" is the Unicode string
Font[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
for (Font font : fonts)
{
  if (font.canDisplayUpTo(myText) < 0) {
    System.out.println(font.getName());
  }
}
// based on the font names in the above output, I will set the font for the editor instance.

I have set myText value as a combination of Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) characters and one supplementary character (that has an associated glyph), like Hi all. The last character is U+10000. I ran the above code. Got no output. So none of the existing fonts supports this string. Is this correct?
From where does Java AWT identify the fonts installed? Does it check somewhere on my system? If yes, where?
I tried searching over the web. I found that I need to select a font that supports all the Unicode glyphs. From my research, I found that GNU Unifont supports the maximum number of glyphs. So I am trying to use it.
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("/path/to/unifont/otf/or/ttf"));
     font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 11);

Even with Unifont, I can't display my string. I notice that there are separate TTF/OTF files for each plane - BMP, supplementary plane 1, supplementary plane 15 etc. I came to know that one TTF can support only 65535 glyphs (because of 16-bit unsigned integer limit). Is this correct?
If the limit is 65535 glyphs, how do I set the font that displays all glyphs? Is it possible to merge two TTFs/OTFs?

I have set myText value as a combination of...   How did you do that in code exactly?

I put "Hi all" in the application's text area and checked each UTF-16 code unit using the contents of the document - it matches.

BTW on my Windows, the Sans Serif Collection font can display U+10000 (correctly on Swing, String myText = Character.toString(0x10_000)) and using 1st posted code snippet; but it cannot display "Hi all" + U+10000" (myText = "Hi all"+ Character.toString(0x10_000)) !

`` is displayable by Code2001

@user85421 - yes, agree. We can use a font that displays U+10000 (). But the same font cannot be used to display the entire string i.e., "Hi all". Is there a solution for it? We can only use 1 font for the entire text in the editor...

@g00se - yes, it seems that Code2001 can be used for U+10000, but my concern is about displaying every character. There must be a way to display all characters in my Java application... Is that possible?

I'm not aware of a font that promises to display all (ever expanding) Unicode codepoint

@g00se yeah, I understand that. I was wondering if we have fonts that keep updating with the Unicode version changes, for example like Unifont (https://unifoundry.com/unifont/). Thank you.

I personally don't know of one

What exactly is your "Unicode string"? Give examples of a few of your problematic characters.

@BasilBourque Few examples I want to work with are "Hi all", "Hi ‍♂️". The first string is displayed as "Hi all" followed by tofu. The second one is displayed as "Hi ♂" - I can't see the faceplam emoji, only the gender modifier is shown. However, when I click left key on my keyboard, I can see it takes more than 1 keystroke for the caret to move to the left - so emoji code points are there, but not visible. How do I fix this?

Specify your host OS and your version of Java. And try different console apps — be sure your console app is set to use UTF-8 as its character encoding. Many consoles are set for non-Unicode encoding, which  astounds me in 2024.

Similar, but JavaFX instead of Swing: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79127168/642706

tl;dr
Nope, not a font problem.
There is some kind of problem when displaying text within Swing, whereas no problem showing the same text in console.
Read on to cover the basics of Unicode characters in Java, and details about your specific characters. Finally we see an example Swing app showing the mysterious problem in Swing vs no problem in console.
To display a character, some font must have glyph

like Hi all. The last character is U+10000.

That is simple to do.
int codePoint = 0x10000 ;  //  = LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A
String x = Character.toString ( codePoint ) ;

Dump to console.
System.out.println ( x + " = " + codePoint + " = " + Character.getName ( codePoint ) );

See this code run at Ideone.com.

 = 65536 = LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A

You said:

But many characters are being shown as tofus, which I think is a font issue.

Yes, that might be a font problem.
The modern desktop & mobile OSes (macOS, iPadOS, iOS, Android, Windows, Linux, BSD, etc.) all provide rich font services. An app can specify one or more preferred fonts, to be used first in finding a glyph to display. If those preferred fonts lack a glyph, the OS moves on to other fonts, looking for a glyph. If none are found, some “fall-back” font defaults. That font-of-desperation may have a crude glyph or may display a “tofu” empty box or question mark or some such.
Code point
To represent a single character, use a code point integer number. Every one of the 154,998 characters defined in Unicode is permanently assigned a number in the range of 0 to 1,114,111 (U+10FFFF), its code point.
Your example character  is code point 65,536 (U+10000). The official name is LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A.
Get a string with this character via its code point.
int codePoint = 0x10000;  // Or: = 65_536 ;
String x = Character.toString ( codePoint );

Dump to console.
System.out.println ( x + " = " + codePoint + " = " + Character.getName ( codePoint ) );

On my console, I see:

 = 65536 = LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A

… so I do not have a font problem. Some font on my Mac was found to have a glyph for that character.
Font class
If you are curious as to which fonts have a glyph for that character, write code similar to this. We call upon the Font class.
List < Font > hasGlyph = new ArrayList <> ( );
List < Font > noGlyph = new ArrayList <> ( );
Font[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment ( ).getAllFonts ( );
for ( Font font : fonts )
{
    if ( font.canDisplay ( codePoint ) ) hasGlyph.add ( font );
    else noGlyph.add ( font );
}

Dump to console.
System.out.println ( "----|  Has Glyph  |----------------------------" );
hasGlyph.stream ( ).map ( font -> font.getFontName ( Locale.of ( "en" , "US" ) ) ).forEach ( System.out :: println );

System.out.println ( "\n----|  No Glyph  |----------------------------" );
noGlyph.stream ( ).map ( font -> font.getFontName ( Locale.of ( "en" , "US" ) ) ).forEach ( System.out :: println );
System.out.println ( "---------------------------" );

When I run this on macOS Sonoma 14.7 (United States), I see a long list of fonts with a glyph for that character.
----|  Has Glyph  |----------------------------
Serif
SansSerif
Monospaced
Dialog
DialogInput
.SFNS-Bold
.SFNS-Regular
AcademyEngravedLetPlain
AlBayan
AlBayan-Bold
AlNile
AlNile-Bold
AlTarikh
AmericanTypewriter
AmericanTypewriter-Bold
AmericanTypewriter-Condensed
AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold
AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight
AmericanTypewriter-Light
AmericanTypewriter-Semibold
AndaleMono
Apple-Chancery
AppleBraille
AppleBraille-Outline6Dot
AppleBraille-Outline8Dot
AppleBraille-Pinpoint6Dot
AppleBraille-Pinpoint8Dot
AppleColorEmoji
AppleGothic
AppleMyungjo
AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold
AppleSDGothicNeo-ExtraBold
AppleSDGothicNeo-Heavy
AppleSDGothicNeo-Light
AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium
AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular
AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold
AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin
AppleSDGothicNeo-UltraLight
AppleSymbols
Arial-Black
Arial-BoldItalicMT
Arial-BoldMT
Arial-ItalicMT
ArialHebrew
ArialHebrew-Bold
ArialHebrew-Light
ArialHebrewScholar
ArialHebrewScholar-Bold
ArialHebrewScholar-Light
ArialMT
ArialNarrow
ArialNarrow-Bold
ArialNarrow-BoldItalic
ArialNarrow-Italic
ArialRoundedMTBold
ArialUnicodeMS
Avenir-Black
Avenir-BlackOblique
Avenir-Book
Avenir-BookOblique
Avenir-Heavy
Avenir-HeavyOblique
Avenir-Light
Avenir-LightOblique
Avenir-Medium
Avenir-MediumOblique
Avenir-Oblique
Avenir-Roman
AvenirNext-Bold
AvenirNext-BoldItalic
AvenirNext-DemiBold
AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic
AvenirNext-Heavy
AvenirNext-HeavyItalic
AvenirNext-Italic
AvenirNext-Medium
AvenirNext-MediumItalic
AvenirNext-Regular
AvenirNext-UltraLight
AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic
AvenirNextCondensed-Bold
AvenirNextCondensed-BoldItalic
AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold
AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic
AvenirNextCondensed-Heavy
AvenirNextCondensed-HeavyItalic
AvenirNextCondensed-Italic
AvenirNextCondensed-Medium
AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic
AvenirNextCondensed-Regular
AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLight
AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLightItalic
Ayuthaya
Baghdad
BanglaMN
BanglaMN-Bold
BanglaSangamMN
BanglaSangamMN-Bold
Baskerville
Baskerville-Bold
Baskerville-BoldItalic
Baskerville-Italic
Baskerville-SemiBold
Baskerville-SemiBoldItalic
Beirut
BigCaslon-Medium
BodoniOrnamentsITCTT
BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-Bold
BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-Book
BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-BookIta
BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-Bold
BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-Book
BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-BookIt
BodoniSvtyTwoSCITCTT-Book
BradleyHandITCTT-Bold
BrushScriptMT
CanelaText-Bold
CanelaText-BoldItalic
CanelaText-Medium
CanelaText-MediumItalic
CanelaText-Regular
CanelaText-RegularItalic
Chalkboard
Chalkboard-Bold
ChalkboardSE-Bold
ChalkboardSE-Light
ChalkboardSE-Regular
Chalkduster
Charter-Black
Charter-BlackItalic
Charter-Bold
Charter-BoldItalic
Charter-Italic
Charter-Roman
Cochin
Cochin-Bold
Cochin-BoldItalic
Cochin-Italic
ComicSansMS
ComicSansMS-Bold
Copperplate
Copperplate-Bold
Copperplate-Light
CorsivaHebrew
CorsivaHebrew-Bold
CourierNewPS-BoldItalicMT
CourierNewPS-BoldMT
CourierNewPS-ItalicMT
CourierNewPSMT
DINAlternate-Bold
DINCondensed-Bold
Damascus
DamascusBold
DamascusLight
DamascusMedium
DamascusSemiBold
DecoTypeNaskh
DevanagariMT
DevanagariMT-Bold
DevanagariSangamMN
DevanagariSangamMN-Bold
Didot
Didot-Bold
Didot-Italic
DiwanKufi
DiwanMishafi
DiwanMishafiGold
DiwanThuluth
EuphemiaUCAS
EuphemiaUCAS-Bold
EuphemiaUCAS-Italic
Farah
Farisi
Futura-Bold
Futura-CondensedExtraBold
Futura-CondensedMedium
Futura-Medium
Futura-MediumItalic
GB18030Bitmap
Galvji
Galvji-Bold
Galvji-BoldOblique
Galvji-Oblique
GeezaPro
GeezaPro-Bold
Geneva
Georgia
Georgia-Bold
Georgia-BoldItalic
Georgia-Italic
GillSans
GillSans-Bold
GillSans-BoldItalic
GillSans-Italic
GillSans-Light
GillSans-LightItalic
GillSans-SemiBold
GillSans-SemiBoldItalic
GillSans-UltraBold
GranthaSangamMN-Bold
GranthaSangamMN-Regular
GujaratiMT
GujaratiMT-Bold
GujaratiSangamMN
GujaratiSangamMN-Bold
GurmukhiMN
GurmukhiMN-Bold
GurmukhiSangamMN
GurmukhiSangamMN-Bold
Helvetica
Helvetica-Bold
Helvetica-BoldOblique
Helvetica-Light
Helvetica-LightOblique
Helvetica-Oblique
HelveticaNeue
HelveticaNeue-Bold
HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic
HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack
HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold
HelveticaNeue-Italic
HelveticaNeue-Light
HelveticaNeue-LightItalic
HelveticaNeue-Medium
HelveticaNeue-MediumItalic
HelveticaNeue-Thin
HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic
HelveticaNeue-UltraLight
HelveticaNeue-UltraLightItalic
Herculanum
HiraMaruProN-W4
HiraMinProN-W3
HiraMinProN-W6
HiraginoSans-W0
HiraginoSans-W1
HiraginoSans-W2
HiraginoSans-W3
HiraginoSans-W4
HiraginoSans-W5
HiraginoSans-W6
HiraginoSans-W7
HiraginoSans-W8
HiraginoSans-W9
HiraginoSansGB-W3
HiraginoSansGB-W6
HoeflerText-Black
HoeflerText-BlackItalic
HoeflerText-Italic
HoeflerText-Ornaments
HoeflerText-Regular
ITFDevanagari-Bold
ITFDevanagari-Book
ITFDevanagari-Demi
ITFDevanagari-Light
ITFDevanagari-Medium
ITFDevanagariMarathi-Bold
ITFDevanagariMarathi-Book
ITFDevanagariMarathi-Demi
ITFDevanagariMarathi-Light
ITFDevanagariMarathi-Medium
Impact
InaiMathi
InaiMathi-Bold
JetBrainsMono-Italic
JetBrainsMono-Italic_Bold-Italic
JetBrainsMono-Italic_ExtraBold-Italic
JetBrainsMono-Italic_ExtraLight-Italic
JetBrainsMono-Italic_Light-Italic
JetBrainsMono-Italic_Medium-Italic
JetBrainsMono-Italic_SemiBold-Italic
JetBrainsMono-Regular
JetBrainsMono-Regular_Bold
JetBrainsMono-Regular_ExtraBold
JetBrainsMono-Regular_ExtraLight
JetBrainsMono-Regular_Light
JetBrainsMono-Regular_Medium
JetBrainsMono-Regular_Thin
JetBrainsMono-SemiBold
JetBrainsMono-ThinItalic
JetBrainsMonoNL-Bold
JetBrainsMonoNL-BoldItalic
JetBrainsMonoNL-ExtraBold
JetBrainsMonoNL-ExtraBoldItalic
JetBrainsMonoNL-ExtraLight
JetBrainsMonoNL-ExtraLightItalic
JetBrainsMonoNL-Italic
JetBrainsMonoNL-Light
JetBrainsMonoNL-LightItalic
JetBrainsMonoNL-Medium
JetBrainsMonoNL-MediumItalic
JetBrainsMonoNL-Regular
JetBrainsMonoNL-SemiBold
JetBrainsMonoNL-SemiBoldItalic
JetBrainsMonoNL-Thin
JetBrainsMonoNL-ThinItalic
Kailasa
Kailasa-Bold
KannadaMN
KannadaMN-Bold
KannadaSangamMN
KannadaSangamMN-Bold
Kefa-Bold
Kefa-Regular
KhmerMN
KhmerMN-Bold
KhmerSangamMN
KohinoorBangla-Bold
KohinoorBangla-Light
KohinoorBangla-Medium
KohinoorBangla-Regular
KohinoorBangla-Semibold
KohinoorDevanagari-Bold
KohinoorDevanagari-Light
KohinoorDevanagari-Medium
KohinoorDevanagari-Regular
KohinoorDevanagari-Semibold
KohinoorGujarati-Bold
KohinoorGujarati-Light
KohinoorGujarati-Medium
KohinoorGujarati-Regular
KohinoorGujarati-Semibold
KohinoorTelugu-Bold
KohinoorTelugu-Light
KohinoorTelugu-Medium
KohinoorTelugu-Regular
KohinoorTelugu-Semibold
Kokonor
Krungthep
KufiStandardGK
LaoMN
LaoMN-Bold
LaoSangamMN
LucidaGrande
LucidaGrande-Bold
Luminari-Regular
MalayalamMN
MalayalamMN-Bold
MalayalamSangamMN
MalayalamSangamMN-Bold
MarkerFelt-Thin
MarkerFelt-Wide
Menlo-Bold
Menlo-BoldItalic
Menlo-Italic
Menlo-Regular
MicrosoftSansSerif
Monaco
MonotypeGurmukhi
Mshtakan
MshtakanBold
MshtakanBoldOblique
MshtakanOblique
MuktaMahee-Bold
MuktaMahee-ExtraBold
MuktaMahee-ExtraLight
MuktaMahee-Light
MuktaMahee-Medium
MuktaMahee-Regular
MuktaMahee-SemiBold
Muna
MunaBlack
MunaBold
MyanmarMN
MyanmarMN-Bold
MyanmarSangamMN
MyanmarSangamMN-Bold
Nadeem
NewPeninimMT
NewPeninimMT-Bold
NewPeninimMT-BoldInclined
NewPeninimMT-Inclined
Noteworthy-Bold
Noteworthy-Light
NotoNastaliqUrdu
NotoNastaliqUrdu-Bold
NotoSansBatak-Regular
NotoSansKannada-Black
NotoSansKannada-Bold
NotoSansKannada-ExtraBold
NotoSansKannada-ExtraLight
NotoSansKannada-Light
NotoSansKannada-Medium
NotoSansKannada-Regular
NotoSansKannada-SemiBold
NotoSansKannada-Thin
NotoSansMyanmar-Black
NotoSansMyanmar-Bold
NotoSansMyanmar-ExtraBold
NotoSansMyanmar-ExtraLight
NotoSansMyanmar-Light
NotoSansMyanmar-Medium
NotoSansMyanmar-Regular
NotoSansMyanmar-SemiBold
NotoSansMyanmar-Thin
NotoSansNKo-Regular
NotoSansOriya
NotoSansOriya-Bold
NotoSansTagalog-Regular
NotoSerifMyanmar-Black
NotoSerifMyanmar-Bold
NotoSerifMyanmar-ExtraBold
NotoSerifMyanmar-ExtraLight
NotoSerifMyanmar-Light
NotoSerifMyanmar-Medium
NotoSerifMyanmar-Regular
NotoSerifMyanmar-SemiBold
NotoSerifMyanmar-Thin
Optima-Bold
Optima-BoldItalic
Optima-ExtraBlack
Optima-Italic
Optima-Regular
OriyaMN
OriyaMN-Bold
OriyaSangamMN
OriyaSangamMN-Bold
PTMono-Bold
PTMono-Regular
PTSans-Bold
PTSans-BoldItalic
PTSans-Caption
PTSans-CaptionBold
PTSans-Italic
PTSans-Narrow
PTSans-NarrowBold
PTSans-Regular
PTSerif-Bold
PTSerif-BoldItalic
PTSerif-Caption
PTSerif-CaptionItalic
PTSerif-Italic
PTSerif-Regular
Palatino-Bold
Palatino-BoldItalic
Palatino-Italic
Palatino-Roman
Papyrus
Papyrus-Condensed
PartyLetPlain
Phosphate-Inline
Phosphate-Solid
PingFangHK-Light
PingFangHK-Medium
PingFangHK-Regular
PingFangHK-Semibold
PingFangHK-Thin
PingFangHK-Ultralight
PingFangSC-Light
PingFangSC-Medium
PingFangSC-Regular
PingFangSC-Semibold
PingFangSC-Thin
PingFangSC-Ultralight
PingFangTC-Light
PingFangTC-Medium
PingFangTC-Regular
PingFangTC-Semibold
PingFangTC-Thin
PingFangTC-Ultralight
PlantagenetCherokee
ProximaNova-Bold
ProximaNova-BoldIt
ProximaNova-Extrabld
ProximaNova-ExtrabldIt
ProximaNova-Light
ProximaNova-LightIt
ProximaNova-Medium
ProximaNova-MediumIt
ProximaNova-Regular
ProximaNova-RegularIt
ProximaNova-Semibold
ProximaNova-SemiboldIt
PublicoText-Bold
PublicoText-BoldItalic
PublicoText-Italic
PublicoText-Roman
PublicoText-Semibold
PublicoText-SemiboldItalic
Raanana
RaananaBold
Rockwell-Bold
Rockwell-BoldItalic
Rockwell-Italic
Rockwell-Regular
STHeitiSC-Light
STHeitiSC-Medium
STHeitiTC-Light
STHeitiTC-Medium
STIXTwoMath-Regular
STIXTwoText
STIXTwoText-Italic
STIXTwoText-Italic_Bold-Italic
STIXTwoText-Italic_Medium-Italic
STIXTwoText-Italic_SemiBold-Italic
STIXTwoText_Bold
STIXTwoText_Medium
STIXTwoText_SemiBold
STSong
STSongti-SC-Black
STSongti-SC-Bold
STSongti-SC-Light
STSongti-SC-Regular
STSongti-TC-Bold
STSongti-TC-Light
STSongti-TC-Regular
Sana
Sathu
SavoyeLetPlain
ShreeDev0714
ShreeDev0714-Bold
ShreeDev0714-BoldItalic
ShreeDev0714-Italic
SignPainter-HouseScript
SignPainter-HouseScriptSemibold
Silom
SinhalaMN
SinhalaMN-Bold
SinhalaSangamMN
SinhalaSangamMN-Bold
Skia-Regular
Skia-Regular_Black
Skia-Regular_Black-Condensed
Skia-Regular_Black-Extended
Skia-Regular_Bold
Skia-Regular_Condensed
Skia-Regular_Extended
Skia-Regular_Light
Skia-Regular_Light-Condensed
Skia-Regular_Light-Extended
SnellRoundhand
SnellRoundhand-Black
SnellRoundhand-Bold
SukhumvitSet-Bold
SukhumvitSet-Light
SukhumvitSet-Medium
SukhumvitSet-SemiBold
SukhumvitSet-Text
SukhumvitSet-Thin
Symbol
Tahoma
Tahoma-Bold
TamilMN
TamilMN-Bold
TamilSangamMN
TamilSangamMN-Bold
TeluguMN
TeluguMN-Bold
TeluguSangamMN
TeluguSangamMN-Bold
Thonburi
Thonburi-Bold
Thonburi-Light
TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT
TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT
TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT
TimesNewRomanPSMT
Trattatello
Trebuchet-BoldItalic
TrebuchetMS
TrebuchetMS-Bold
TrebuchetMS-Italic
Verdana
Verdana-Bold
Verdana-BoldItalic
Verdana-Italic
Waseem
WaseemLight
Webdings
Wingdings-Regular
Wingdings2
Wingdings3
ZapfDingbatsITC
Zapfino

… and:
----|  No Glyph  |----------------------------
---------------------------

FACE PALM
You asked about the emoji “face palm” characters.
The basic character , named FACE PALM, is decimal 129,318 (U+1F926).
int codePoint = 129_318; // 129_318 =  = FACE PALM

To get man facepalming, you need multiple code points. Emojis in Unicode have variation such as skin tone and sex defined by combining a basic emoji with some modifying code points. See the Unicode web site for details.
We can use hex numbers in series.
String manFacepalming = "\uD83E\uDD26\u200D\uFE0F"; // ‍♂️

Or use a literal character.
String manFacepalming = "‍♂️";

Dump to console.
System.out.println ( "manFacepalming = " + manFacepalming + " = " + manFacepalming.codePoints ( ).boxed ( ).toList ( ).toString ( ) );

manFacepalming = ‍♂️ = [129318, 8205, 9794, 65039]
No font has every glyph
Be aware that no font has a glyph for every character in Unicode.
Attempts have been made, but technical problems ensue. Not to mention the enormous workload of designing over 150,000 glyphs with any reasonable amount of harmony and quality.
Swing
Let’s try running similar code within a Swing app as well as on the console.
package work.basil.example.type;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SwingGlyph
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI ( )
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "HelloWorldSwing" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        // This code modified from here: https://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/java/ta_scroll/
        // Create Scrolling Text Area in Swing
        String text =
                new StringBuilder ( )
                        .appendCodePoint ( 65_536 ) //  = 65536 = LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A
                        .append ( "\n" )
                        .appendCodePoint ( 129_318 ) // 129_318 =  = FACE PALM
                        .append ( "\n" )
                        .append ( "‍♂️" )  // man facepalming = ‍♂️ = [129318, 8205, 9794, 65039]
                        .append ( "\n" )
                        .append ( "« fin »" )
                        .toString ( );
        System.out.println ( text );
        var textArea = new JTextArea ( text , 5 , 50 );
        textArea.setLineWrap ( true );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane ( textArea );
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
        frame.getContentPane ( ).add ( scrollPane );

        // Display the window.
        frame.setPreferredSize ( new Dimension ( 400 , 300 ) );
        frame.pack ( );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ( )
        {
            public void run ( )
            {
                createAndShowGUI ( );
            }
        } );
    }
}

When run on Java 23 on macOS Sonoma, on the console we see this:


‍♂️
« fin »

But in Swing on Java 23 on macOS Sonoma we see this screenshot:

There we see problems similar to what you report: The first character shows an empty “tofu” rectangle rather than the actual character. And the man-facepalming shows a gender sign beside the principal emoji.
I have proven your problem. But I cannot solve it. I do not use Swing, so I do not know the problem or limitation that is ruining the display of our text.
JavaFX
For a contrast, I tried JavaFX.
Interestingly, I did have a problem rendering certain characters, but different from the Swing problem.

 appears as a stripped box, equivalent to Swing.
‍♂️ (Man Facepalming) appears as FACE PALM followed by an A with a diacritical.

Running Java 23.0.1 with JavaFX 23.0.1 on macOS Sonoma.

Meanwhile, as with Swing, we the text appear correctly on the console within IntelliJ IDEA 2024.3 EAP.  So the problem certainly lies within JavaFX or my inexperienced use of JavaFX.


‍♂️
« fin »

Source code for JavaFX app:
package work.basil.example.exunicodeglyph;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage ) throws IOException
    {
        Scene scene = this.makeScene ( );
        stage.setTitle ( "Hello!" );
        stage.setScene ( scene );
        stage.show ( );
    }

    private Scene makeScene ( )
    {
        // Widgets
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea ( );
        String text =
                new StringBuilder ( )
                        .appendCodePoint ( 65_536 ) //  = 65536 = LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A
                        .append ( "\n" )
                        .appendCodePoint ( 129_318 ) // 129_318 =  = FACE PALM
                        .append ( "\n" )
                        .append ( "‍♂️" )  // man facepalming = ‍♂️ = [129318, 8205, 9794, 65039]
                        .append ( "\n" )
                        .append ( "« fin »" )
                        .toString ( );
        System.out.println ( text );
        textArea.textProperty ( ).set ( text );

        // Arrange
        StackPane root = new StackPane ( );
        root.getChildren ( ).add ( textArea );
        return new Scene ( root , 320 , 240 );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        HelloApplication.launch ( );
    }
}

I posted a similar Question about this JavaFX problem.

Avoid char
By the way, avoid the char type in Java. That type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, char is physically incapable of representing most characters.
Instead, use code point integer numbers to work with individual characters. You will find codePoint related methods on classes like Character, String, StringBuilder, etc.

Thanks for the detailed answer. It seems we can't do it in Swing. Wonder how Swing offers support for glyphs from multiple fonts at the same time. Also, it will be interesting to find out how popular text editors handle all these glyphs at the same time (ofc not java swing)...

I would like to know more about GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts(); - from where does Java get these fonts - somewhere on the system where I can do a lookup? Thanks.

@AnandS The list you see here is a combination of the rich collection of fonts Apple includes with macOS plus a few I have installed. The host OS provides fonts to the JVM. Years ago Java came bundled with a set of fonts, but no longer.

I did some testing. I did not explicitly set any font in my code, so java picked it up on its own. What I did was change java versions for my tests- jdk11, 17, 21 and 23 on macOS. The font used by Java in all the cases was "LucidaGrande" but the display of glyphs was different. Using jdk11 displays no emojis whereas jdk17, 21 and 23 was better. Can you explain why? Thanks.

Additionally, now I set the font to "Unifont" (I downloaded unifont-16.0.01) and the results were a bit similar. JDK11 does not show proper glyphs where JDK 17, 21 and 23 do. Wonder why...

I recently stumbled over a problem I did not investigate further but might be connected to your problem. The Font you use might not be the font you actually get. You expect to get the font face told by font.getName() but instead, AWT picks one of the font faces having the same value for font.getFamily(). Which may be reasonable when, e.g. saying “draw with font "Arial" but bold style” and end up with the "Arial Bold" font face. However, tons of fonts are wrongly reported to have the family "Dialog" and whenever trying to draw text with one of them, you may end up with any of the others.
