Certain characters fail to render properly in JavaFX but appear correctly on the console
My input text:
String text =
        new StringBuilder ( )
                .appendCodePoint ( 65_536 ) //  = 65536 = LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A
                .append ( "\n" )
                .appendCodePoint ( 129_318 ) // 129_318 =  = FACE PALM
                .append ( "\n" )
                .append ( "‍♂️" )  // man facepalming = ‍♂️ = [129318, 8205, 9794, 65039]
                .append ( "\n" )
                .append ( "« fin »" )
                .toString ( );

The console correctly shows this:


‍♂️
« fin »

… but JavaFX shows the first and third lines incorrectly:

 What must I do to make a javafx.scene.control.TextArea in JavaFX properly render such characters?
Obviously not a font problem. The very same String object renders correctly on the console, at the same time, in the same app, with the same JDK.

Running Java 23.0.1, with OpenJFX 23.0.1, on IntelliJ IDEA 2024.3 EAP, on macOS Sonoma 14.7 (United States edition).
The JavaFX code for this minimal example app:
package work.basil.example.exunicodeglyph;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage ) throws IOException
    {
        Scene scene = this.makeScene ( );
        stage.setTitle ( "Hello!" );
        stage.setScene ( scene );
        stage.show ( );
    }

    private Scene makeScene ( )
    {
        // Widgets
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea ( );
String text =
        new StringBuilder ( )
                .appendCodePoint ( 65_536 ) //  = 65536 = LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A
                .append ( "\n" )
                .appendCodePoint ( 129_318 ) // 129_318 =  = FACE PALM
                .append ( "\n" )
                .append ( "‍♂️" )  // man facepalming = ‍♂️ = [129318, 8205, 9794, 65039]
                .append ( "\n" )
                .append ( "« fin »" )
                .toString ( );
        System.out.println ( text );
        textArea.textProperty ( ).set ( text );

        // Arrange
        StackPane root = new StackPane ( );
        root.getChildren ( ).add ( textArea );
        return new Scene ( root , 320 , 240 );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        HelloApplication.launch ( );
    }
}

The Maven POM file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExUnicodeGlyph</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ExUnicodeGlyph</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>23</source>
                    <target>23</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>work.basil.example.exunicodeglyph/work.basil.example.exunicodeglyph.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


This Question is similar to this one, but here the topic is JavaFX rather than Swing.
The third line problem may be due to this unresolved bug, [Text] Enhance support for user-perceived characters (grapheme clusters). But that bug does not explain the first line problem with character .

Most probably a font problem.

I tried this with a very simple SWT program on macOS 15.0.1 and the display is OK, which suggests it isn't a font problem.

@talexmovedtoCodidact Obviously not a font problem. The very same String object renders correctly on the console, at the same time in the same app with the same JDK, as explained in the Question.

@BasilBourque are you sure console use same font?

macOS presents the JVM with a large number of rich fonts. If the default font does not contain a glyph, another font should be used automatically.  On my Mac, all of those fonts support the character of the first line. For proof, see my code in my Answer on a similar Question about Swing.

@talexmovedtoCodidact To clarify my comments… I mean the problem is not due to a lack of fonts containing a glyph for these problematic characters. The core of the problem is indeed likely to be font-related in that JavaFX is failing to fall-back to alternative fonts provided by the host OS. Furthermore, given that all fonts on my Mac report as supporting that first character, I suspect that JavaFX may contain some font(s) of its own, and is refusing to look elsewhere for glyphs. No matter how you slice it, it seems that JavaFX is buggy in its text rendering (ditto Swing).

@BasilBourque, why not specify the font explicitly? I know for a fact that the free Code2001 has the glyph

To me, it looks like a bug or non-implemented feature.  A bug report/feature request can be filed if desired.

@jewelsea The third line problem may be due to this unresolved bug, Enhance support for user-perceived characters (grapheme clusters). But that bug does not explain the first line problem with character ``.

@jewelsea I did file a bug report titled the same as this Question. Thank you.
